# Can I use a Motorola Atrix without a SIM card?

Tags: sim-card

My company purchased an Atrix for app development and would like to use it without a SIM card.  Unfortunately, on boot it is not possible to get past the "No SIM card. Emergency calls only" screen.  Is it possible to use the Motorola Atrix without a SIM card?

Edit: Is it also possible to skip or bypass the MotoBlur registration screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can bypass the SIM card requirement by playing with the boot options:

1. Load Boot menu by holding the Volume Down button while starting the phone.
2. Press the Volume Down button until the option "Boot Android (NO BP)" appears at the top of the screen.
3. Press the Volume Up button to select this option.
4. On load, the phone will bypass the No SIM card screen

Next, you can either register for a MotoBlur account or skip it by entering the following keys into the virtual keyboard (press and hold the Menu key to bring up the keyboard):

- ?123
- ALT
- ABC
- e
- ?123
- ALT
- ABC
- e
- b
- l
- u
- r
- o
- f
- f

Luckily, this process only needs to be performed once.  It looks like the phone remembers this boot option for next time :)  Thanks to XDA for the MotoBlur bypass steps!

Comment: Is everything working fine? I'm planning to buy an android tablet (without SIM/data plan) and use it for development testing and stuff, and I was wondering if you mind sharing what other hiccups you have met?

Comment: I haven't run into any issues with this approach.  You can still access the internet via Wifi.  The only things you can't do (as far as I've noticed) are make phone calls or send text msgs.

Comment: Heys cool, did you tryout the location stuff and Google Maps to see if its working fine as well ?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you have a data connection via Wifi or some other means.  The GPS always works regardless of a dataplan.

Comment: What happen if it went wrong...Is there any possibilities messing up the phone

Comment: @Pacerier - The issue you would have with Maps is that, if you have no data plan, you'll have to remember to cache your trip before you start it (off wifi). Otherwise, the maps can't update on the fly as you drive.