# Use Android Phone like an iPod Touch (without SIM)

Tags: sim-card

I'm using a Motorola Atrix 2 for testing at work, don't want to use my SIM with it.

When I startup the phone I get an emergency calls only page and I can't get past it.

I have had a look at this very related question:

[Can I use a Motorola Atrix without a SIM card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6649/can-i-use-a-motorola-atrix-without-a-sim-card)

but I seem to have a different experience than the suggested solution says I should.

When I try to boot with the volume down button pressed down and then press the volume down button again, I never end up seeing "Boot Android (NO BP)". The top of my screen only ever says "AP Fastboot Flash Mode (S)". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a Motorola Atrix 2 at hand, but as far my memory goes, you can go past the 
"No SIM/Emergency Dial Only" screen if you boot the phone while holding the camera button pressed.